# Background not working in Java Spring app on Heroku

Tags: java, html, css, spring, heroku

Help me with my problem. There is do not working backgroundfor pages on the Heroku after I deploing my Java Spring app, althout it work on my local maschine.

I have following code in the file style.css:

```
.coderovka-fon {

  background-image: url('/coderovka-fon-2.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;   

}
```

and on html page:

```
<body class="coderovka-fon">
```

Please, help me with my problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. Previously, I tried to take the merged from the style.css, but it doesn't work that way. I had to insert the style tag into tag header of the html page and then everything works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).